# How to remove application settings entirely with uninstallation

Tags: c#, installation, settings, uninstallation

I have an application I've built that makes use of Settings to store the user's parameters for next launch. So on a FRESH computer, never before installed on, the first time opening this application the parameters have an intialized value of 0. However after the user changes these and closes and then reopens the program, the parameters display those most recently entered values.

Now let's say I uninstall the program, then reinstall it and boot it up. I should see 0s in those parameters again right?

WRONG. For some reason the last used parameters are displayed. How? Shouldn't these be removed upon uninstallation? Why does it do this?

Comment: how are you determining if this is a new installation vs someone that uninstalled..? there must be a save somewhere that you are using. and if during the uninstall process..if there is a Settings why can't you set the instance of settings to Null then before final close reinitialize the settings to default values or have a logical trigger that would determine this for example perhaps using the registry or some other file to track this ...

Comment: If the app-version and such result in the same hash, the old settings will get picked up.  Increment the version number of the assembly.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks this worked : )

Comment: It didnt remove the old ones, they just arent automatically found.  I think if you `.Update` they will get picked up depedning on the change